# Passing a DateTime Variable to a Console Application using Cmd Prompt

Tags: c#, .net, dos

I hope you can help.

I have a console application that needs to receive a datetime value, so for example 2015-12-01 00:00:00.000, but the time part does not get picked up because of the space between the date and the time. I have 3 variables I am passing : (2 integers and 1 Datetime)

Cmd Prompt :

```
C:\Application1.exe 3935 1 2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

Is there a way I can pass through the date and time as 1 variable, like '2015-12-01 00:00:00.000' ?

Ive tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Put quotes around it: `C:\Application1.exe 3935 1 "2015-12-01 00:00:00.000"`

Comment: What error messages do you get? How does the start of your program regarding the input look like?

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a go and let you know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, encapsulate it into quotes and parse it from a string:

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(args[2]);
```

Or a saver appraoch would be using [DateTime-TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
if (DateTime.TryParse(out date)) { /* do anything with the date */ }
```

Call it like:

```
C:\Application1.exe 3935 1 "2015-12-01 00:00:00.000"
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your second suggestion, but im getting the following error : No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 argument.

Comment: I used your First suggestion as well as the way it was called, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Add a `T`:

```
C:\Application1.exe 3935 1 2015-12-01T00:00:00.000
```

This should work if you use `DateTime.Parse` to convert and you won't have to mess with spaces.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a go as well and let you know.